# Video intend can't be used on android (Appcelerator)

Tags: android, video, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Video recording works fine on IOS, Android can't catch data.

problem seems to be the

```
var curActivity = Ti.Android.currentActivity;
curActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, function(e) { ....
```

there was some advise to use win.getActivity() instead, but i have no variable I can use. 
$.cameraWin 
this 
is not working.
Any advise?

## index.xml

```html
<Alloy>
    <TabGroup>        
    <Tab id="websiteTab" title="Web">
            <Require backgroundColor="black" color="white" id="webTab" src="website" type="view"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab id="cameraTab" title="Camera">
            <Require backgroundColor="black" color="white" id="cameraTab" src="camera" type="view"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab backgroundColor="black" color="white" id="loginTab" title="Login">
            <Require backgroundColor="black" color="white" id="loginTab" src="login" type="view"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab backgroundColor="black" color="white" id="registerTab" title="Map">
            <Require backgroundColor="black" color="white" id="registerTab" src="register" type="view"/>
        </Tab>
    </TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

## camera.xml

```html
<Alloy>
    <Window id="cameraWin">
        <Label id="Label_1" text="Gib Deinem Video einen Namen"/>
        <TextField id="TextField_1"/>
        <Button id="Button_1" onClick="doClick" title="Aufnehmen und hochladen"/>
        <ProgressBar id="ProgressBar_1"/>
        <Picker id="Picker_1" selectionIndicator="true" useSpinner="true">
            <PickerColumn id="PickerColumn_1" title="Kategorie">
                <Row title="Fußball"/>
                <Row title="Handball"/>
                <Row title="Schifahren"/>
                <Row title="Einkehren"/>
            </PickerColumn>
        </Picker>
        <Label id="Label_2" text="Veranstaltung/Kategorie"/>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

## camera.js

```js
function doClick(e) {
  Ti.API.info(Titanium.Platform.osname);
  if (Titanium.Platform.osname == 'iphone') {
    //record for iphone
    $.ProgressBar_1.value = 0;
    $.ProgressBar_1.message = "Hochladen"
    Titanium.Media.showCamera({
      success: function(event) {
        var video = event.media;
        movieFile = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(
          Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,
          'mymovie.mov');

        movieFile.write(video);
        videoFile = movieFile.nativePath;
        var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
        xhr.onload = function(e) {
          Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
            title: 'Success',
            message: 'status code ' + this.status
          }).show();
          Ti.API.info(this.responseText);
        };
        xhr.open('POST', 'XXXXXXXXXX');
        xhr.send({
          Filedata: event.media,
          /* event.media holds blob from gallery */
          title: $.TextField_1.value,
          catid: 17
        });
        // onsendstream called repeatedly, use the progress property to
        // update the progress bar
        xhr.onsendstream = function(e) {
          $.ProgressBar_1.value = e.progress * 100;
          $.ProgressBar_1.message = "Hochladen von Video";
          Ti.API.info('ONSENDSTREAM - PROGRESS: ' + e.progress * 100);

        };


      },
      cancel: function() {},
      error: function(error) {
        // create alert
        var a =
          Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
            title: 'Video'
          });

        // set message
        if (error.code == Titanium.Media.NO_VIDEO) {
          a.setMessage('Device does not have video recording 
                            capabilities ');
        } else {
          a.setMessage('Unexpected error: ' + error.code);
        }

        // show alert
        a.show();
      },
      mediaTypes: Titanium.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO,
      videoMaximumDuration: 120000,
      videoQuality: Titanium.Media.QUALITY_MEDIUM
    });
  } else {

    var intent = Titanium.Android.createIntent({
      action: 'android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE'
    });
    Ti.API.info('Intent created. ..');
    var curActivity = Ti.Android.currentActivity;
    curActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, function(e) {
      if (e.error) {
        Ti.UI.createNotification({
          duration: Ti.UI.NOTIFICATION_DURATION_LONG,
          message: 'Error: ' + e.error
        }).show();
      } else {
        Ti.API.info('Drinnen');
        Ti.Api.info(e.resultCode);
        if (e.resultCode === Titanium.Android.RESULT_OK) {
          Ti.API.info('Drinnen');
          videoFile = e.intent.data;
          var source = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(videoFile);
          var movieFile =
            Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'mymovie.3gp');
          Ti.API.info('Sichert');
          source.copy(movieFile.nativePath);
          Titanium.Media.saveToPhotoGallery(movieFile);
          var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
          xhr.onload = function(e) {
            Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
              title: 'Success',
              message: 'status code ' + this.status
            }).show();
            Ti.API.info(this.responseText);
          };
          var fileContent = movieFile.read();
          Ti.API.info('Video rauf');
          xhr.open('POST', 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
            Filedata: fileContent,
            /* event.media holds blob from gallery */

            title: $.TextField_1.value,
            catid: 17
          });
          // onsendstream called repeatedly, use the progress property to
          // update the progress bar
          xhr.onsendstream = function(e) {
            $.ProgressBar_1.value = e.progress * 100;
            $.ProgressBar_1.message = "Hochladen von Video";
            Ti.API.info('ONSENDSTREAM - PROGRESS: ' + e.progress * 100);

          };
        } else {
          Ti.UI.createNotification({
            duration: Ti.UI.NOTIFICATION_DURATION_LONG,
            message: 'Canceled/Error? Result code: ' +
              e.resultCode
          }).show();
        }
      }
    });

  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative way:**

I'm currently working on getting video recording to android in the normal SDK:
https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/pull/7929

It is already working (Samsung Galaxy S6 has a problem a the moment I need to fix: you need to rotate the phone ones to have the proper preview size) but needs some more testing. With this you can use the back/front camera to record video the same way as on iOS.

But it still needs some time to be in the GA version. You can always compile an own sdk for yourself if you need it right away (I can provide a linux build).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar project, though mine is taking stills, not video, but for all intents and purposes they should behave the same.

In my code I have:

```
var win = $.camera_view;
```

This allows me later to start my activity with:

```
win.activity.startActivityForResult(...
```

Per your example you would probably set curActivity like this:

```
var curActivity = $.cameraWin.activity;
```

[EDIT]

If you still get no result you can try using .putExtraUri to specify the location to store the video:

```
var tempfile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory, "tempvideo.mpg");
intent.putExtraUri("output",tempfile.nativePath);
```

You would set this before calling startActivityForResult.